# i try to use jetpack compos and i design simple app display a list of tasks each one have an expandable button shows information but not working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

i try to use jetpack compos and i design simple app display a list of tasks each one have an expandable button shows information but not working at all its clickable but nothing happened when i try to click on it just the animation that makes you know that the icon is clicked but nothing else
here is my code
MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.thirtydayoftasks

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.annotation.StringRes
import androidx.compose.animation.animateContentSize
import androidx.compose.animation.core.Spring
import androidx.compose.animation.core.spring
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.foundation.shape.RoundedCornerShape
import androidx.compose.material.Card
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.IconButton
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ExpandLess
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ExpandMore
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.draw.clip
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.example.thirtydayoftasks.model.Task
import com.example.thirtydayoftasks.model.tasks
import com.example.thirtydayoftasks.ui.theme.ThirtyDayOfTasksTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ThirtyDayOfTasksTheme {
                ThirtyDayOfTasksApp()
            }
        }
    }
}
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun ThirtyDayOfTasksApp() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            ThirtyDayOfTasksTopAppBar()
        }
    ) {

        LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.background)) {
            items(tasks) {
                TaskItem(task = it)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskItem(
    task: Task,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Card(
        modifier = modifier.padding(8.dp),
       elevation = 4.dp
    ) {

        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .animateContentSize(
                    animationSpec = spring(
                        dampingRatio = Spring.DampingRatioMediumBouncy,
                        stiffness = Spring.StiffnessLow
                    )
                )) {
            Column (
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                TaskDay(dayRes = task.dayRes)
                TaskImage(imageRes = task.imageRes)
                TaskTitle(titleRes = task.titleRes)
            }
            DescriptionIcon(expanded = expanded, onClick = { expanded = !expanded })
            if (expanded){
                TaskDescription(descriptionRes = task.descriptionRes)
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ThirtyDayOfTasksTopAppBar(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.app_name),
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
        )
    }
}


@Composable
fun TaskDescription(
    @StringRes descriptionRes:Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = descriptionRes),
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(8.dp),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.body2
    )
}



@Composable
fun TaskDay(
    @StringRes dayRes:Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Text(text = stringResource(id = dayRes),
        modifier = modifier
            .padding(top = 8.dp),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h1
    )
}


@Composable
fun TaskImage(
    @DrawableRes imageRes: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(8.dp)
            .clip(
                RoundedCornerShape(
                    4
                )
            )
    ) {
        Image(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            painter = painterResource(id = imageRes),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.FillWidth
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun TaskTitle(
    @StringRes titleRes:Int,
){
    Text(
        text = stringResource(id = titleRes),
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2
    )
}

@Composable
private fun DescriptionIcon(
    expanded: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
){
    IconButton(onClick = { onClick }) {
        Icon(imageVector = if (expanded)Icons.Filled.ExpandLess else Icons.Filled.ExpandMore,
            tint = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary,
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true, showSystemUi = true)
@Composable
fun ThirtyDaysOfTasksAppPreview(){
    ThirtyDayOfTasksTheme(darkTheme = false) {
        ThirtyDayOfTasksApp()
    }
}

@Preview(showSystemUi = true, showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ThirtyDaysOfSuccessAppPreviewDark(){
    ThirtyDayOfTasksTheme(darkTheme = true) {
        ThirtyDayOfTasksApp()
    }
}
```

help me

i tried different ways to resolve the problem but no i think the problem in TaskDescription function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in this line: `IconButton(onClick = { onClick })` - you created onClick lambda for IconButton but inside it you didn't invoke the another lambda that comes from the method's arguments, so to make it work you can do one of this things:

1. add invocation of the lambda from the method's arguments like this: `IconButton(onClick = { onClick() })` or `IconButton(onClick = { onClick.invoke() })`
2. just pass the lambda from the method's arguments to `IconButton` onClick argument like this: `IconButton(onClick = onClick)`

Comment: thx it works with invoke but i have another issues now because my extendable button above the information but thx i just will try now to do something with that